# Designing an upper triangular table in ASP.net codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, html, html-table

So i have a stupid problem, sorry but i'm a starter in HTML and design... What i'm trying to achieve is an upper triangular table, i'm creating my table in asp.net codebehind here is my code;

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        TableRow r = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 3; j > i; j--)
        {
            TableCell c = new TableCell()
            {
                Height = 100,
                Width = 100,
                ColumnSpan = j,
                BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
            };
            r.Cells.Add(c);
        }
        bottomRightTable.Rows.Add(r);
    }
```

So basically what i want to get is this (sorry for my mad paint skills but i wanted to make my self clear) and again sorry if this is a stupid question but i'm not very experienced with asp.net yet and i don't want to use any dummy table cells i want to use 6 cells if i want to create a triangle starts with 3.

Thanks a lot for all the help!

Image for help;
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly have no idea if this will work, but try:

```
bottomRightTable.Attributes["dir"] = "RTL"; // Set the table to "right-to-left"
```

Theoretically, it should make the right column 0, the middle column 1, and the left column 2....so you'll have to reverse any other logic.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1.1

---

Your algorithm is using ColumnSpan but it's not doing anything.  That's because it sets the ColumnSpan to the same value for every cell in the column. ie:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="..."></td>
        <td colspan="2" style="..."></td>
        <td style="..."></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="..."></td>
        <td colspan="2" style="..."></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="..."></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you try to fix the ColumnSpan algorithm, you'd end up with:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="..."></td>
        <td style="..."></td>
        <td style="..."></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="..."></td>
        <td style="..."></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="..."></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: squares]

So, basically, I think you either need to use the right-to-left hack or use empty cells.

Comment: it was magic it definitely was! so simple yet so amazing! thank you it worked! And thank you again for the algorithm! i just wrote that to show my intentions and will definitely fix it!

Comment: @umutto: you're welcome.  _(I updated my answer because I wasn't happy with it before.)_

Comment: =) Thanks for the help! and i really appreciate! Your answer is one of the best i've ever seen you know with the picture, example codes and stuff! only if i could vote twice! Anyway i'm not even using columnSpan anymore and it works, thanks to the "RTL" attribute. I don't really know how it works in background but i believe its some nice feature with asp table! And it seems allright. Again thanks for everything!